# Vb.net Connection String for Ms Access Database

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, ms-access-2010

What is the connection string for connecting MS Access 2010  (.accdb) database in VB.net.

Comment: @Yatrix Google. It might lead you here. Look at his rating... obviously new.

Answer (score 5):

connectionstrings.com is a [wonderful thing](http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007):

> **Standard security**
>
> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
>
> **With database password**
>
> This is the connection string to use when you have an Access 2007
>   database protected with a password using the "Set Database Password"
>   function in Access.
>
> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database
>   Password=MyDbPassword;
>
> Some reports of problems with password longer than 14 characters. Also
>   that some characters might cause trouble. If you are having problems,
>   try change password to a short one with normal characters.
>
> **DataDirectory functionality**
>
> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=|DataDirectory|\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security
>   Info=False;

Answer (score 3):

You may use `Server Explorer` of Visual Studio to get the connection string or take a look at  the [connection](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) string.

Answer (score 1):

www.connectionstrings.com

this is a good site for connection strings for almost any application

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect to the  database by using
'Tools->Connect to database' ?

If you have already done the above, try this:

Go to server explorer.
And select connected database -> In its properties there is a connection string -> Copy it and paste into your code.