# Access Database Connection String

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, connection

I have built an application that connects to an access database on one of my servers at work.  I can easily use this on my computer but when I install on another I obviously have an issue specifying the connection to the database location on the server.  How do I allow the user to specify the database connection location for use on multiple work stations? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830318/vb-net-connection-string-for-ms-access-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not hard-code the filename of the DB in your code, rather store it in a configuration file. E.g. an INI-file or an XML-file. See [How to store and retrieve custom information from an application configuration file by using Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/313405).

---

You can save the setting in the App.Config File like this.

```
Const  connectionKey As String = "connection"

Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration

config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
config.AppSettings(connectionKey) = openFileDialog.FileName
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

And you can read it again with

```
Dim value As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(connectionKey)
```

(Not tested. Got it from here: [Read/Write App.Config File with .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET).)

Comment: I'm still stuck... I've created an open file dialog that passes the connection to a text box. How do I get it to pass it to the DB connection string? Sorry I am new to this :-(

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how to pass the information from the openfiledialog to the app.config connection string file?