# Cannot update an MSAccess database in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access, vb6, visual-studio-2013

I have integrated an MSAccess database in Visual Studio 2013, working within Visual Basic. It works, but cannot update the information in the database. When I insert records from Visual Basic and click on Save, the record appears to be saved. But if I close the form in Visual Studio and re-open, the record disappears.

Comment: Which application in Visual Studio are you talking about?  C#?  J++?  Visual Basic?

Comment: Visual basic for windows app

Comment: Are you positive your connection string is correct?  Take a look at this answer to make sure you're set up properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830318/vb-net-connection-string-for-ms-access-database

Comment: yes its correcct , i add db information , it show me in VB , but when i close progam and i reopen  my information disappear

Comment: Try stepping through your code.  There must be an untrapped error somewhere in your Update/AddNew statement.  Data doesn't disappear from a database, so the only answer is that it's never actually being written to it.  As proof, you can open your Access DB right after you click your Save button and you will see the data is not there.

Comment: You say you have verified the connection works? Could you post the code relevant to the save?  Also, like Johnny suggested, remove anything that may be skipping the error.  This is why I hate `on error resume next`